# Header file skipped when looking for precompiled header use

Tags: c++

Could you help me understand what the problem is?
I seem to have included `stdafx.h`.
Then I tried to rebuild the solution. Tried to clean the solution.
And anyway I get this:

```
c:\...\tetris\figure_factory.cpp(2): warning C4627: '#include "figure_factory.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\...\tetris\tetris\figure_factory.cpp(3): warning C4627: '#include "figure.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
```

And of course the full set of mistakes following from the absence of the header files.

My files:

```
figure_factory.cpp


#pragma once
#include "figure_factory.h"
#include "figure.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#define stop __asm nop

Figure I;
I.shape = {
            {{0, 0, 0, 0}, 
             {1, 1, 1, 1},
             {0, 0, 0, 0},
             {0, 0, 0, 0}},
......



figure_factory.h

#pragma once
#include "figure.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#define stop __asm nop


class Figure_Factory{
    const int figure_number = 5; 
    const int colour_number = 5; 

    public:
        Figure get_figure(int type, int colour);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stdafx.h` must come as first include file if you are using precompiled headers and Microsoft compiler.
And you must not include it in other include files.
And `#pragma once` is useless in `.cpp` files

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility: You've got a header file which is marked as a source file. In Visual Studio, right-click the header file and in Configuration Properties > General > Item Type check that you have "C/C++ header", not "C/C++ compiler".

This is an easy mistake to make when manually editing the .vcxproj file, by typing <ClCompile> instead of <ClInclude>.